# Shutting down my windows 8.1, it says Screenshot App not responding, but i dont have any such apps installed

Tags: windows-8, virus, screenshot, phishing

Shutting down my windows 8.1, it says Screenshot App not responding, but i dont have any such apps installed.
I have done a search a and found nothing remotely like it.
could this be a hidden virus/phishing program?

Comment: The answer that exist as of now is both good and bad.  Malwarebytes is an excellent suggestion, but i don't like the way it starts out... with "not really"....i'm pretty sure you most likely have some maleware

Answer (score -1):

Not really, it may be built in. Try getting Malwarebytes (just Google and get the trial) and run a scan using it. If there is, it'll find it for sure.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).